# live http with node.js make server performance bad?

Tags: node.js

If use node.js create a http server.

Then use

```
res.write()
```

to response something to client.

That is use live http connection, server will not disconnect to client by itself.
Will it make server performance bad because too many connection?

Answer (score 0):

It's not good to hold too many connections.

I think you should try [sockit.io](http://socket.io)?